# WebView doesn't consider blank pages in WebHistory

Tags: java, javafx, webview

When a blank page (i.e. `about:blank`) is loaded in a `WebView` by its `WebEngine`, the `WebHistory` doesn't add that `Entry`. That information is relevant for properly implementing back and forward buttons (similar to current browsers).

One possible solution would be to add an `Entry` to `WebHistory`, but that's not allowed.

If that behavior is intentional, how can you implement back and forward buttons considering blank pages without creating your own history `List`?

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebHistory;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;

public class App extends Application {

    private WebView webView;
    
    private WebEngine webEngine;
    
    private WebHistory webHistory;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        webView = new WebView();
        
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        
        webHistory = webEngine.getHistory();
        
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (Worker.State.SUCCEEDED.equals(newVal)) {
                print();
            }
        });
        
        Button button1 = new Button("Google");
        Button button2 = new Button("Stack Overflow");
        Button button3 = new Button("Empty");
        
        button1.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.load("http://www.google.com"));
        button2.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.load("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
        button3.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.load(""));
        
        HBox buttons = new HBox(10, button1, button2, button3);
        
        VBox root = new VBox(10, buttons, webView);
        
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        
        stage.show();
    }
    
    private List<String> history() {
        return webHistory.getEntries().stream().map(WebHistory.Entry::getUrl).toList();
    }

    private void print() {
        System.out.println("Location: " + webEngine.getLocation());
        System.out.println("Current index: " + webHistory.getCurrentIndex());
        System.out.println("History: " + history() + System.lineSeparator());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

In this example, if you press the buttons from left to right, you get:

```
Location: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
Current index: 0
History: [https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl]

Location: https://stackoverflow.com/
Current index: 1
History: [https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl, https://stackoverflow.com/]

Location: about:blank
Current index: 1
History: [https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl, https://stackoverflow.com/]
```

Instead, I would expect the last entry to be:

```
Location: about:blank
Current index: 2
History: [https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl, https://stackoverflow.com/, about:blank]
```

Comment: In addition to blank page, webEngine().loadContent(String) also is not kept in the history.